# Error in Dynamic PIVOT Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I am getting error in Dynamic PIVOT Table.

I have a Tables like 
TT_Child

```
TTChild_ID      TT_ID       Roll_No     Std_Reg_ID      Attendance
1             3               1         22                     1
2             3               2         23                     0
```

and  Table

TT_Master

```
TT_ID   Attend_date  Time_from  Time_To   Course_ID  Faculty_ID  Acad_Year  Subject_ID
    1   2014-03-01  10:00   11:00       1         16     2013-2014     34
    2   2014-03-02  10:00   11:00       1         16     2013-2014        34
    3   2014-03-03  10:00   11:00       1         16     2013-2014    34
```

Student_Registration_Master

```
Std_Reg_ID  Stud_FNAME  stud_MNAME  Stud_MNAME
```

--I am using this PIVOT query but getting this error. I have to use Attend_Date and Time as a Column Name.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Attendance_Test]
    @courseid as int=null, @acadyear nvarchar(15)=null
AS

Declare @colList varchar(max)
Declare @qry varchar(max)

SET @colList = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), TTM.Attend_Date, 103)) + ' '+ QUOTENAME(TTM.Time_From)
             FROM TT_Child SA
             inner join TT_Master TTM on SA.TT_ID = TTM.TT_ID
             where (TTM.Course_ID = @courseid) 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('/', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

SET @qry = 'SELECT SA.Reg_ID, STUD_FNAME +  STUD_MNAME + STUD_LNAME as [Student Name], '+@colList+' 
   FROM 
     (
        select SA.Reg_ID, SR.STUD_FNAME, SR.STUD_MNAME, SR.STUD_LNAME, TTM.Attend_Date , SA.Attendance from TT_Child SA
        inner join TT_Master TTM on SA.TT_ID = TTM.TT_ID
        inner join STUDENT_Registration_MASTER SR on CR.Reg_ID = SR.STUD_Reg_ID
        where (TTM.Course_ID = '+cast(@courseid as varchar(50))+ ') and (TTM.Acad_Year = '''+@acadyear+''')
        group by SA.Reg_ID, SR.STUD_FNAME, SR.STUD_MNAME, SR.STUD_LNAME, TTM.Attend_Date, SA.Attendance
     ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Attendance) FOR Attend_Date IN (' + @colList + ')
    ) pvt'
print(@qry)
Exec(@qry)
```

-- I am getting this error message

```
SELECT SA.Reg_ID, STUD_FNAME +  STUD_MNAME + STUD_LNAME as [Student Name], [01/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[02/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[03/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[05/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[05/03/2014] [11:00:00.0000000] 
  FROM 
     (
       select SA.Reg_ID, SR.STUD_FNAME, SR.STUD_MNAME, SR.STUD_LNAME, TTM.Attend_Date , SA.Attendance from TT_Child SA
        inner join TT_Master TTM on SA.TT_ID = TTM.TT_ID
        inner join STUDENT_Registration_MASTER SR on CR.Reg_ID = SR.STUD_Reg_ID
        where (TTM.Course_ID = 1) and (TTM.Acad_Year = '2013-2014')
        group by SA.Reg_ID, SR.STUD_FNAME, SR.STUD_MNAME, SR.STUD_LNAME, TTM.Attend_Date, SA.Attendance
     ) as s
   PIVOT
    (
       MAX(Attendance) FOR Attend_Date IN ([01/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[02/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[03/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[05/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[05/03/2014] [11:00:00.0000000])
    ) pvt
```

Error Message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '10:00:00.0000000'.
```

Plz give solution

Answer (score 1):

When you review this line of your code you will see the error:

```
MAX(Attendance) 
FOR Attend_Date IN ([01/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[02/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],
                    [03/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],[05/03/2014] [10:00:00.0000000],
                    [05/03/2014] [11:00:00.0000000])
```

The date and the time have each been wrapped in square brackets separately so you will get an error.

You need to concatenate the date and time together first, then wrap in square brackets using `QUOTENAME`. You should be able to change the code to:

```
SET @colList 
  = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), TTM.Attend_Date, 103) + ' '+ TTM.Time_From)
             FROM TT_Child SA
             inner join TT_Master TTM on SA.TT_ID = TTM.TT_ID
             where (TTM.Course_ID = @courseid) 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('/', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03c92/3) of your version and this new version.

Comment: I know it. But how can I get in square brackets? I have tried this.. QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), TTM.Attend_Date, 103) + ' '+ TTM.Time_From)

Comment: @QuaBiz I'm not sure I understand your question, the example that I provided demonstrates how to get the two columns into a single set of square brackets.

Comment: Can u tell me please how to add two columns in this  PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Attendance) FOR Attend_Date,Time_from IN (' + @colList + ')
    ) pvt '

Comment: @QuaBiz Are you trying to PIVOT the values of 2 columns?  If so I would suggest editing your question and providing the final desired result.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to PIVOT the values of 2 columns. and I have mentioned this ----I am using this PIVOT query but getting this error. I have to use Attend_Date and Time as a Column Name.

Comment: @QuaBiz But what do you want as the final result?  Seeing the final result would make it much easier to determine what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am storing daily attendance of student date wise and time wise, i want this attendance in following format  . Eg. Reg_ID, Name, Date1_&_Time_attendance, Date2_&_Time_Attendance, ... etc. Result like  1   XYZ  1  1  0  .... like this